# Accessing ngModel in Directive's controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom form element directive that includes some child directives. I require `ngModel` in the parent directive so that I can use `ng-model="object.data"` on the directives HTML declaration.

The problem I have is changing that value from the child directives. The child directives can require the parents controller function but that controller function does not have access to the `ngModelController` which is only (I could be wrong here) available to the `postLink` function.

Both the `Controller` and `Link` functions have access to the same scope (in this case, it is not always true) so I can do something like:

```
.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {

        ....

        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            this.select = function (selected) {
                $scope.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(selected);
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.ngModelCtrl = ngModelCtrl;

        }
    };
}])

.directive('myChildDirective', [function () {
    return {
        require: '^myDirective',
        ....

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, myDirectiveCtrl) {
            elem.bind('click', function () {
                myDirectiveCtrl.select(scope.value);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

By assigning the `ngModelController` to the scope I can access it in a controller function method which in turn can be called by a child directive but this seems pretty hacky and there must be a better solution so any help would be much appreciated.

Please see my [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xJASvT?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish, but why not just use ng-click on the element, and handle it in the parent controller completely?

And if you need to modify something from the parent scope, inject that object into the child scope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/w4AcNdWPOdVsfy0OmEc6?p=preview

Comment: That is perfect if I want to bind to a click event. I was looking for a way for the child to set the parents `ng-model` value in general, not specifically on a click event (if possible). By injecting the object into the child scope do you mean inject the ngModel value and have a `$watch` expression in the parent to call `ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue()`?